# Analyze Firebase App results based on original URL?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-firebase

We have various routes of getting users to install our app.  Each source uses a different url, i.e. play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app&source_name=XYZ
or
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app&source_name=ABC

In Firebase Analytics dashboard I'm able to see all my user activity and all I want to do is breakdown my Firebase analytics based on that source_name parameter.  # of users for ABC vs XYZ.  Seems like it should be simple but I don't know where this parameter would show up?

I've searched forums and clicked all over the analytics UI, but haven't found anything.

BTW, we are also sending them through a Firebase page.link before they get to the google play store.